# SOAP web service API call from eclipse project is taking long time than the call from SOAP UI

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I have generated client code from web service and trying to invoke a method, it is taking almost 4-5 minutes to get the response from the server where as from SoapUI it's just took 1 or 2 seconds to respond.
Could you please help me out on what causes this delay in the response?

Comment: We're gonna need to see some code

Comment: This is the direct call to the API,
 java.lang.Object _resp = _call.invoke(new java.lang.Object[] {domainId, username, password});

Answer (score 0):

Check where the delay is happening when parsing the response. I have faced the same once, but finally I found it is not with the call, but due to the delay in parsing the data and executing the logic on data there after. So first better you to check the time taken for the immediate response after the call. If it is not the issue, then share your code.

Comment: It took more than 5 minutes to get the response after the direct cal to the server which means the problem is not with the parsing the data and executing but the API call only. I am not really sure how it works differently from the SoapUI?